# reverse the direction of the links in doors module

Tags: ibm-doors

I have tried the below code but this does not work can any one help me to fix the same -

```
Module m = current
Object o = current 
Object src,trg
Link lnk 
ModName_ targetMod 
int sabno,tabno
string obj_type 
//print "Source \t Destination"
/*for o in m do*/ {
                for lnk in o->"*" do {
                                                targetMod = target lnk
                                read(fullName(targetMod),false)             
                                //sabno = sourceAbsNo(lnk)
                                //tabno = targetAbsNo(lnk)
                                src = source(lnk)
                                trg = target(lnk)
                                delete(lnk) 
                                //trg -> "/Harley_MY19_Phoenix/99 Link Modules/SRS_to_CRS" -> src
                                trg <- "/Harley_MY19_Phoenix/99 Link Modules/SRS_to_CRS" <- src 
                                //break
                }
                //break
}
infoBox "*****************Complete*********************************"
```

How do i fix the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below code works to revers the out going to incoming links, hope this helps you -

```
Module m = current
Object o = current 
Object src,trg
Link lnk 
ModName_ targetMod 
int sabno,tabno
string obj_type 
for o in m do {
                for lnk in o->"*" do {
                                                targetMod = target lnk
                                edit(fullName(targetMod))               
                                src = source(lnk)
                                trg = target(lnk)
                                delete(lnk) 
                                trg -> "/Harley_MY19_Phoenix/99 Link Modules/SRS_to_CRS" -> src 
                }
}
infoBox "*****************Complete*********************************"
```